# How to get product url by SKU?

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking for a way to get Full Product URL by SKU I input. Any Ideas? I saw some code how to get product full URL for export (http://t3jsot.blogspot.cz/2011/08/magento-export-products-with-full-urls.html)

But how to get a full product URL of SKU I specify? So for example I need the full URL of "B004QRKWKQ" SKU and boom I get it. It's part of my system to show relevante content on the fly. I have researched and failed.